# Copying files via system call fails on PHP

Tags: php, system-calls, cp

I try to copy some files from one directory on server to another, but it does not work.

Here is my code:

```
system('cp /var/www/site1/images/' . $row['imageUrl']. ' /var/www/site2/content/upload/content/item/mid/' . $row['imageUrl']);
```

Comment: Why you don't use php dedicated copying functions?

Comment: Any errors? Return value from system-call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$file = '/var/www/site1/images/'.$row['imageUpl'];
$newfile = '/var/www/site2/content/upload/content/item/mid/'.$row['imageUpl'];

if (copy($file, $newfile)) {
    echo "success";
}
else
{
    echo "failed";
}
```

Look at the `copy()` function here: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.copy.php